# Is there a way to export then import custom connector from one environment to another

Tags: office-365, power-automate, powerapp, custom-connector, power-platform

I created a custom connector inside our development tenant, now I want to built it inside 5 tenants for our clients.

So can I export and import this custom connector across tenants? OR I will need to manually re-create them 5 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom connector in a solution in power platform environment.

Then you can export the solution and import it in another environment/tenant.

[image]

Check the documentation of Power platform solutions at: [Solutions overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview)

Comment: thanks for your reply.. so will this custom connector be available to Power Automate as well as Power Apps?

Comment: Yes, it's available at environment level.